# C# IndexOf function not working as expected

Tags: c#, html

So, I'm fairly new to coding, but I've never had a problem with IndexOf until now. I'm trying to search through an html string which looks like:

> " data-pid=\"6598160343\">\n\n        https://minneapolis.craigslist.org/dak/fuo/d/executive-desk-3-piece-set/6598160343.html\"
>   class=\"result-image gallery\"
>   data-ids=\"1:00B0B_hkRi5TEyM9Q,1:00z0z_jTtBxHxlxAZ,1:00p0p_2GU15WOHDEB,1:00909_eKQVd7O1pfE\">\n
>   $1500\n        \n\n    \n        \n            favorite this post\n
>   \n\n            Jun 
>   4\n\n\n        https://minneapolis.craigslist.org/dak/fuo/d/executive-desk-3-piece-set/6598160343.html\"
>   data-id=\"6598160343\" class=\"result-title hdrlnk\">Executive Desk (3
>   piece set)\n\n\n        \n
>   $1500\n\n\n\n                \n                    pic\n
>   map\n
>   \n\n                \n                    hide this posting\n
>   \n\n            \n            \n                restore\n                restore this posting\n
>   \n\n        \n
>
> \n\n         "  string

I'm trying to find the index of specific elements so that I can grab the data later, here's what I have to find the indexes of the positions on either side of the data I want:

```
DataBookends bkEnds = new DataBookends
        {
            PIDFrom = (post.IndexOf(@"pid=\""")) + (@"pid=\""".Length),
            URLFrom = (post.IndexOf(@"<a href=\")) + (@"<a href=\".Length),
            PriceFrom = (post.IndexOf(@"result-price\"">$")) + (@"result-price\"">$".Length),
            DateFrom = (post.IndexOf(@"datetime=\""")) + (@"datetime=\""".Length),
            TitleFrom = (post.IndexOf(@"result-title hdrlnk\"">")) + (@"result-title hdrlnk\"">".Length),
            LocationFrom = (post.IndexOf(@"result-hood\""> (")) + (@"result-hood\""> (".Length)
        };
        bkEnds.PIDTo = post.IndexOf(@"\""", bkEnds.PIDFrom);
        bkEnds.URLTo = post.IndexOf(@"\", bkEnds.URLFrom);
        bkEnds.PriceTo = post.IndexOf(@"</span>", bkEnds.PriceFrom);
        bkEnds.DateTo = post.IndexOf(@"\", bkEnds.DateFrom);
        bkEnds.TitleTo = post.IndexOf(@"</a>", bkEnds.TitleTo);
        bkEnds.LocationTo = post.IndexOf(@"\", bkEnds.LocationFrom);

        return bkEnds;
```

However, whenever I try to run it, it either doesn't find anything, or the index values are incorrect. I know I'm missing something simple but I can't figure it out and I feel like a moron. Is it something to do with escape characters I'm not seeing or something with how my string is formatted?
Help please?

EDIT:
I initially tried using the HTML Agility Pack, but I was having trouble understanding how to extract the data I needed so I thought using string.substring() would've been more straightforward.
The index values I'm getting are entirely wrong, even before I tried adding the forward-slashes. I'll be getting rid of those.

Comment: Is there a chance that the string you're viewing is escaped but the string you're operating on isn't?

Comment: Not the question you're asking, but have you looked into the HTML Agility Pack?

Comment: I'd stop now and bury this code and use the HTML Agility Pack instead.

Comment: Besides the comments about the bigger picture, what index values are you getting that are wrong?  Presumably you are expecting the -1 you get from `IndexOf` if there is no match (which of course you are adding to the Length).

Comment: I'm guessing you pulled your sample string out of the debugger. Those backslash characters that the debugger displays aren't actually in the string, they just show up in the debugger output because the debugger shows the value as a quoted string so it needs to escape them. Your actual string is most likely `data-pid="6598160343">\n\n ...`

Comment: I initially tried using the HTML Agility Pack, but I was having trouble understanding how to extract the data I needed so I thought using string.substring() would've been more straightforward. The index values I'm getting are entirely wrong, even before I tried adding the forward-slashes.

Comment: You had a problem, then tried to solve it with a library you need to learn about, had a problem, then trying to solve it the wrong way and had more problems. The thing to be a good programmer is to be able to weigh this up and choose where to spend your time. As the comments describe, you should not attempt to parse html yourself, it will bite you just about every time, its unmaintainable and it will break easily. You need to bite the bullet and use a dedicated parser, you will lose your hair (and go grey) less quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, I ended up going with HTML Agility Pack as was suggested by Jeremy. I wasn't able to figure out what exactly was wrong with how I was searching through it with IndexOf and Substring (for example: it would skip "" and continue on until a point that didn't contain any of those characters), but I'm not going to try web-scraping that way again.

For the future, HTML Agility Pack is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

I'll write this answer but really it was CraigW in the comments who spotted your error.  I think it could still use some explaining as you missed it.  Also, the other comments are right that a parser might be the way to go.  I still think you should understand the mistake you made as it's generally useful.

You said the variable has this string

> " data-pid=\"6598160343\">\n\n https://minneapolis.craigslist.org/dak/fuo/d/executive-desk-3-piece-set/6598160343.html\" class=\"result-image gallery\" data-ids=\"1:00B0B_hkRi5TEyM9Q,1:00z0z_jTtBxHxlxAZ,1:00p0p_2GU15WOHDEB,1:00909_eKQVd7O1pfE\">\n $1500\n \n\n \n \n favorite this post\n
>   \n\n Jun 4\n\n\n https://minneapolis.craigslist.org/dak/fuo/d/executive-desk-3-piece-set/6598160343.html\" data-id=\"6598160343\" class=\"result-title hdrlnk\">Executive Desk (3 piece set)\n\n\n \n
>   $1500\n\n\n\n \n pic\n
>   map\n
>   \n\n \n hide this posting\n
>   \n\n \n \n restore\n restore this posting\n
>   \n\n \n
>   \n\n " string

which seems to have come from the debugger.  You're searching with

```
post.IndexOf(@"pid=\""")
```

this won't find a hit, because it is literally looking for `pid=\"` which is not in your variable.  Your variable actually contains

```
data-pid="6598160343">
 https://minneap....
```

The debugger showed it as

```
data-pid=\"6598160343\">\n\n https://minneap
```

because it always 'escapes' quotes (ie a `"` in the variable shows in the watch window as `\"`) and similarly newlines appear as `\n`.  If you click the magnifying glass icon you will see the string as it really is, without the escapes.

Hope that clears your confusion, if it does you will now realise that this code would work

```
post.IndexOf(@"pid=""")
```

Also, for your interest note that if you don't use `@` before a string then you escape the `"`, eg.

```
post.IndexOf("pid=\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your code a little bit because it's really hard to debug. See my code below and get your idea. You can copy and paste the method ExtractData (and the class as well) to your code, but you need to add some code to verify the patterStart, patterEnd can be found from the content

```
using System;

public static class StringFinder
{
    public static string ExtractData(this string content, string patterStart, string patternEnd)
    { 
        var indexStart = content.IndexOf(patterStart) + patterStart.Length;
        var indexEnd = content.IndexOf(patternEnd, indexStart);
        return content.Substring(indexStart,indexEnd - indexStart);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = @" data-pid=\""6598160343\"">\n\n https://minneapolis.craigslist.org/dak/fuo/d/executive-desk-3";

        Console.WriteLine(data.ExtractData(@"data-pid=\""", @"\"">"));
    }
}
```

Result 6598160343